# Running multiple functions based on one imported excel dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created multiple functions for each client, They are all basically the same (it only changes the workers names inside of each one of them).

It runs the first functions as it should, but then the second one does not work. It's like the dataframe isn't being carried out throughout the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

#file loc
R1 = input('Data do Relatório desejado  (dd.mm) --->  ')
loc = r'C:\Users\lucas.mascia\Downloads\relatorio-{0}.xlsx'.format(R1)

#opening file with exact needed columns
df = pd.read_excel(loc)
df = df[[2,15,16,17]]

[...]
def func1():
    global df, R1, bcsulp1, bcsulp2

    #List of solicitantes in Postal Saude
    list_sol = [lista_solic["worker1"]]

    #filter Postal Saude Solicitantes
    df = df[(df['Client']==lista_clientes[2]) 
        & (df['worker'].isin(list_sol))]

    #Alphabetical order
    df = df.sort_index(by=['worker', 'place'])

    #Grouping data of column
    gp = df.groupby('worker')

    # Loop?
    for i in range(1,2):
        df = gp.get_group(list_sol[(i-1)])
        #Name_i         #############################################################
        #Protocolo interno e externo --------------------------------------------
        p_interno = df[(df['place'].str.contains("C. Martins"))
            & (df['task']==lista_tarefas[1])]
        globals()['fi'+str(i)] = len(p_interno)
        f_i = globals()['fi'+str(i)]

        p_externo = df[(~df['place'].str.contains("C. Martins"))
            & (df['task']==lista_tarefas[1])]
        globals()['fe'+str(i)] = len(p_externo)
        f_e = globals()['fe'+str(i)]

        #Protocolo Virtual interno e externo ------------------------------------
        pv_interno = df[(df['place'].str.contains("C. Martins"))
            & (df['task']==lista_tarefas[3])]
        globals()['vi'+str(i)] = len(pv_interno)
        v_i = globals()['vi'+str(i)]

        pv_externo = df[(~df['place'].str.contains("C. Martins"))
            & (df['task']==lista_tarefas[3])]
        globals()['ve'+str(i)] = len(pv_externo)
        v_e = globals()['ve'+str(i)]

        #Protocolo postal normal e especial
        pp_normal = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[51])]
        pp_especial = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[52])]
        globals()['postal'+str(i)] = len(pp_especial) + len(pp_normal)
        post = globals()['postal'+str(i)]

        #Copia integral e parcial 6,1 - 6,2
        copia_i = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[61])]
        copia_p = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[62])]
        globals()['copia'+str(i)] = len(copia_p) + len(copia_i)
        cop = globals()['copia'+str(i)]

        #Copia eletronica
        copia_elet = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[7])]
        globals()['copia_elet'+str(i)] = len(copia_elet)
        cop_e = globals()['copia_elet'+str(i)]

        #AIJ / Audiencia / Conciliatoria
        aij = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[81])]
        aud = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[82])]
        conc = df[(df['task']==lista_tarefas[83])]
        globals()['audiencia'+str(i)] = len(aij) + len(aud) + len(conc)
        audi = globals()['audiencia'+str(i)]


        globals()['bcsulp'+str(i)] = [f_i, f_e, v_i, v_e, post, cop, cop_e, audi]

    def func2(): [...]

    def func3(): [...]

    def func4(): [...]


    func1()
    fucn2()
```

**The following error comes up:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Relatorio_Filtro.py", line 736
    func2()
  File "Relatorio_Filtro.py", line 682
    df = gp.get_group(list_sol[(i-1)])
  File "C:..."
    inds = self._get_index(name)
  File "C:..."
    return self.indices[name]
KeyError: 'WORKER1'
```

**Question:**

Am I missing something so that the excel dataframe imported at the beginnig is carried out throughout the program?

Comment: Can you post data and actual code, it's impossible to comment as this becomes a wild guessing game

Comment: I edit with the first functions, all the others are basically the same only changing the places and workers names according to clients.

Comment: You should fix the indentation in the first code block, too. I'd do it myself but I wouldn't want to fix it the wrong way.

Comment: It seems that the error is in your `func2()` where you're calling the column `WORKER1` (case sensitive) and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Leb was quicker than myself, thank you.

Comment: It does exist @Leb , i tested each function separately before putting them all into one .py file

When i run it continuously, it gets an error on the second function it runs whichever one it is.

Comment: Then like you said, there must be a discontinuity somewhere. I'm only going off what the error is showing, maybe something went out of order when you joined the file?

Comment: It seems to work when I add `gp = df` ... like making a copy of the main dataframe